# Construct a sentence in the empty language.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Consider the following exercise, taken from my course book on model and proof theory:

> Let L be the empty language, so an L-structure is “just” a nonempty
>   set M. Express by means of an L-sentence that M has exactly 4 elements.

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this; somehow, I have to use only variables and the standard logical symbols to "force" the underlying set to be of size four. It seems like it shouldn't be too hard, but I still lack intuition on how to construct such sentences. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to write "there are 4 elements and every $x$ is equal to one of those 4"

Comment: You have no constant, functions and predicate symbols, but you have the logical symbols and "$=$" is (usually) treated as a logical symbol.

Comment: @Manlio So, something like $\exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d\forall x(x=a\vee x=b\vee x=c\vee x=d)$? But that doesn't seem to include unicity. So then I suppose I could replace $x=a$ with $(x=a\wedge\neg(x=b)\wedge\neg(x=c)\wedge\neg(x=d))$, and similarily with the other equalities. However... this seems like such a long sentence to express something so simple. I suppose it's alright if what I said is correct, but, could there be a "simpler" way of writing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way of expressing that $M$ has exactly four elements is
$$\exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d[\neg(a=b\lor a=c\lor a=d\lor b=c\lor b=d\lor c=d)\land\forall x[x=a\lor x=b\lor x=c\lor x=d]]$$
The first set of equalities, wrapped under the negation, means that $a,b,c,d$ are different, so $M$ has at least four elements. The second set of equalities, in the universal quantifier's scope, means that all elements are equal to one of these four, so $M$ has at most four elements. The two combine and force $M$ to have exactly four elements.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I thought of right after writing down my last comment on the question. Nonetheless, very helpfull indeed.